# Objective C equivalent of Swift addConstraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

i am a newbie in autolayout using code.

```
addConstaints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-16-[v0]-16-|",options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics:nil ,views:["v0":thumbnailImageView]))

addConstaints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-16-[v0]-16-|",options:NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics:nil ,views:["v0":thumbnailImageView]))
```

Iam trying to achieve above swift code in Objective C using below code but app crashes on load with below error

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Expected a view 
H: |-16-[v0]-16-| 
  ^'**

```
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[v0]-16-|" 
options:0 
metrics:nil 
views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)]];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-16-[v0]-16-|" 
options:0 
metrics:nil 
views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)]];
```

.....

```
UIImageView * thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        thumbnailImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        thumbnailImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        [self addSubview:thumbnailImageView];


        thumbnailImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Comment: remove the whiteSpace `@"H: |-16-[v0]-16-|"`should be `@"H:|-16-[v0]-16-|"`

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thanks for reply. i tried but still crashes with same error

Comment: @ReinierMelian Your opinion on obj c syntax of swift . Are they equivalent? do i have to make change?

Comment: In Objctive-C code is where you have a whitespace did you check removing it?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes i removed whitespace in Xcode but still crashes

Comment: @ReinierMelian i copied syntax from from https://autolayoutconstraints.com/ do i have to change views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)?

Comment: replace `@"H:|-16-[v0]-16-|"`  by `@"H:|-16-[thumbnailImageView]-16-|"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings`  produces variable bindings that match your Objective-C variable names. So you need to write the constraint as

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[thumbnailImageView]-16-|" 
options:0 
metrics:nil 
views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)]];
```

Or you just skip `NSDictionaryOfVairableDBindings` and use:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[v0]-16-|" 
options:0 
metrics:nil 
views:@{ @"v0" : thumbnailImageView } ];
```

which is a bit more like the Swift version. (Don't have compiler handy just at the moment so might be some small syntax errors in the second part. Will check ASAP).

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrongly the macro `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` you need to pass the variable name instead

> /* This macro is a helper for making view dictionaries for
>   +constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:.    NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v1, v2, v3) is equivalent to
>   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:v1, @"v1", v2, @"v2", v3,
>   @"v3", nil];  */

```
 [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-16-[thumbnailImageView]-16-|" 
options:0 
metrics:nil 
views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)]];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-16-[thumbnailImageView]-16-|" 
options:0 
metrics:nil 
views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(thumbnailImageView)]];
```